# Using sed to change /etc/fstab

Tags: unix, sed

I would like to change `/etc/fstab` inside a script. I want to add the `acl`attribute to the root partition.

One `fstab`line entry looks like this:

```
UUID=730aee20-52b7-4920-75cd-d0d995ef2445 /   ext3   errors=remount-ro 0   1
```

I want to change it to:

```
UUID=730aee20-52b7-4920-75cd-d0d995ef2445 /   ext3    acl,errors=remount-ro 0   1
```

I thought:
 1. Search line with root partition `/` 
 2. insert `acl` after `/`

How can I do that with sed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Who needs some 3rd party tool when we all have `awk`?

```
awk '$2~"^/$"{$4="acl,"$4}1' OFS="\t" /etc/fstab
```

#### Example Output

```
$ awk '$2~"^/$"{$4="acl,"$4}1' OFS="\t" /etc/fstab
/dev/sda2        swap             swap        defaults         0   0
/dev/sda5       /       ext4    acl,defaults    1       1
/dev/sda1        /boot            ext4        defaults         1   2
/dev/sda6        /home            ext4        defaults         1   2
/dev/sdb1        /backup          ext4        defaults         1   2
#/dev/cdrom      /mnt/cdrom       auto        noauto,owner,ro  0   0
/dev/fd0         /mnt/floppy      auto        noauto,owner     0   0
devpts           /dev/pts         devpts      gid=5,mode=620   0   0
proc             /proc            proc        defaults         0   0
tmpfs            /dev/shm         tmpfs       defaults         0   0
```

### Explanation

1. `$2~"^/$"` Search the 2nd field `$2` to see if it matches a forward slash by itself `^/$`
2. `{$4="acl,"$4}` If we see a match, prepend *acl* to the beginning of the 4th field `$4`
3. `}1` This is an `awk` shortcut which is equivalent to `print $0`, i.e. print the whole line (including any alterations we may have made)
4. `OFS="\t"` Set the Output Field Separator `OFS` to a tab `\t`. The default is space
5. `/etc/fstab` The file we want to use as input

Comment: Care to explain the awk features used here? =)

Comment: @everlof you got it, see the newly added **Explanation** section.

Answer (score 4):

I guess the best way would be to use augeas, which is a great tool. With augeas you can parse configuration files automatically, append/delete/update some field with XPATH, which is used to navigate through the XML.

You can find all the supported conifiguration files that augeas can correctly parse in the following directory:

```
/usr/share/augeas/lenses/dist/
```

One of the files is fstab.aug, which is the one you want. You don't actually need to do anything with that files, it's just there to let you know that augeas can do what you want :).

```
# ls /usr/share/augeas/lenses/dist/fstab.aug
/usr/share/augeas/lenses/dist/fstab.aug
```

You can also look here for more detailed example obout changing /etc/fstab through augeas.

[Augeas Example](http://mrpointy.wordpress.com/2010/05/01/augeas-and-appending-lines-to-etcfstab/)

I guess you can use something like the following:

```
# augtool
augtool> set /files/etc/fstab/1[file='/']/opt[1] "acl"
augtool> set /files/etc/fstab/1[file='/']/opt[2] "errors=remount-ro"
augtool> print /files/etc/fstab/1
/files/etc/fstab/1
/files/etc/fstab/1/spec = "/dev/mapper/system"
/files/etc/fstab/1/file = "/"
/files/etc/fstab/1/vfstype = "ext3"
/files/etc/fstab/1/opt[1] = "acl"
/files/etc/fstab/1/opt[2] = "errors=remount-ro"
/files/etc/fstab/1/dump = "0"
/files/etc/fstab/1/passno = "1"
augtool> save
```

If you want to use augeas in a shell script you can just preced the above commands with augtool keyword, so if you want to change the first 'opt' to 'acl' you would do:

```
augtool set /files/etc/fstab/1[file='/']/opt[1] "acl"
augtool set /files/etc/fstab/1[file='/']/opt[2] "errors=remount-ro"
augtool save
```

Look at the original augeas page for more: [Augeas Homepage](http://augeas.net)

Comment: This might be a a good solution but don't need this 3rd party software. My installer needs `acl`- that's the only thing I want to do. Therefore additional software is overkill.

Comment: It is the best solution available. And as you need to install sed, you also need to install augeas (but with most distributions sed is already installed, that's why you think it's already there, I don't need to install another software). Fine, use sed, it works, but it's not the best solution.

Comment: @eleanor This is way overkill for something as simple as the OP's question. This is the kind of stuff `awk` was made for as it has the notion of fields and regular expressions.

Answer (score 2):

Added value to Wes's one - `\w` instead of `[a-zA-Z0-9]`, `\s` instead of space. And it actually works :)

```
sed -e 's:\(.*\)\(/\s*\w*\s*\)\(.*\):\1\2acl,\3:' /etc/fstab
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I won't debate whether sed is the right tool for the job or not (I'm not sure it is), but:

```
sed 's#( / +[a-zA-Z0-9]+ +)#$1acl,#'
```

Which should find the / mount, and add acl just before the 2nd field after the mount point.

Comment: Yes, with sed we can do miracles, but sed just isn't appropriate for this kind of stuff. If you want to learn more, use augeas, as it's the right tool for the job - it does it right and clean (contrary to sed).

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
sed 's|^\S*\s\+/\s\+\S*\s\+|&acl,|' /etc/fstab
```

Answer (score 0):

the following works for me (looking for the "/" (root) mount point and adding "acl," in front of "defaults"):

```
sed -e 's:\(.*\)\(\s/\s\s*\)\(\w*\s*\)\(\w*\s*\)\(.*\):\1\2\3acl,\4\5:' /etc/fstab
```

on the contents of my fstab:

```
/dev/VolGroup00/LogVol00 /                       ext3    defaults        1 1
LABEL=/boot             /boot                   ext3    defaults        1 2
tmpfs                   /dev/shm                tmpfs   defaults        0 0
devpts                  /dev/pts                devpts  gid=5,mode=620  0 0
sysfs                   /sys                    sysfs   defaults        0 0
proc                    /proc                   proc    defaults        0 0
/dev/VolGroup00/LogVol01 swap                    swap    defaults        0 0
```

It groups the contents into five fields (volume, mount point, file-system type, options, everything else) split by whitespace.