# Using sed to change /etc/fstab, Part II

Tags: sed, awk

I am trying to modify `/etc/fstab` with `sed`/`awk`.  Much like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9118123/using-sed-to-change-etc-fstab), however, the solutions in that question aren't *quite* working for me.

I need to add the `nodev` (and `nosuid`) option to `nfs` or `nfs4` mount points.

I have working;

```
awk '$4!~/nodev/&&$3~"nfs"{$4=$4",nodev"}1' OFS="\t" /etc/fstab > /etc/fstab.tmp && mv /etc/fstab.tmp /etc/fstab

awk '$4!~/nosuid/&&$3~"nfs"{$4=$4",nosuid"}1' OFS="\t" /etc/fstab > /etc/fstab.tmp && mv /etc/fstab.tmp /etc/fstab
```

However, it obliterates existing white space and replaces with a single tab.  My question is: **How can I make this change in a less intrusive manner?**  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9118513/1207760) looked promising, but I don't understand it well enough to adapt it to my use.

I am open to solutions other than `sed` or `awk`, but any other tools need to exist in a default Red Hat/CentOS environment (during %post in Kickstart.)

Comment: Why set OFS when you don't want the fields separated uniformly by tabs?  Try leaving OFS unset; `awk` tries to preserve the input spacing when it can.

Comment: If I leave it unset, there's no field separator at all.  It strips all white space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, `awk` does tend to munge whitespace if you change any of the fields.  But this is pretty easy with sed.  If your sed supports `\S` to represent non-whitespace, you can do:

`sed 's/\S\S*/&,nodev/4'` to append `,nodev` to the 4th column.  So try:

```
sed -e '/nfs/{/nodev/!s/\S\S*/&,nodev/4}' -e '/nfs/{/nosuid/!s/\S\S*/&,nosuid/4}'
```

If your sed does not allow `/S`, use `[^  ]` instead (actuall space and a tab inside brackets.)  This does not limit the match of `nfs` to the 3rd column.  Exercise left for the reader.

Comment: Works great and it makes sense. (Mostly..) Thanks!

Comment: I had to do some research to understand how this works.  The 4 refers to the 4th match against the pattern (\S\S*), and the & refers to the match (like \0).

Answer (score 1):

Even though this is a little late--here is a method I use in my KickStart file to alter the /etc/fstab

```
    sed -i '/tmp\s/ s/defaults/rw,nodev,noexec,nosuid/' /etc/fstab
```

Basically, when it sees the line with `/tmp` followed by at least one space--it will do a substitution of the word `defaults` with `rw,nodev,noexec,nosuid`. No fuss, no muss.